# validate name uniqueness then submit the name directly to the database

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-validation

I'm Building a reactive form which make use of this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-qbzcst?file=app%2Ftag.component.ts)

which allows me to filter the tags and create new ones.
what I need to do is when the user add new tag the code should validate that the name is not repeated, then submit the tag to the db if validation passed, otherwise it should show error "tag is repeated" to the user.

I already tried this:

```
 this.myForm= this.fb.group({
          name: ...,
          email: ...,
          tag: ['', null,[this.addTextChip(this.httpServices)]]

        });

 addTextChip(httpService: Services): AsyncValidatorFn {
        // call storeTag service which either add the tag to the DB
        // or return "tag is repeated error" 
        // this function should return null or {'TagExist': true}
  }
```

html:

```
 <input [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
           [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="false"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto"
           (keydown.enter)="addTextChip(chipInput)"
           (input)="textChanged(chipInput.value)"
           autofocus
           #chipInput
          formControlName = "tag"
       />
```

When I excuted the code I had errors related to textChanged() function which says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

before continue working on this, is that's the best way to do this? and if it is why I'm getting this error?

Comment: not use a validator that call a http (it's not efficient). Just in submit, call the http, Your http must be return true or error. In submit subscribe to the http, if return true go on the process (e.g. going to a new page), else show the error and mantein in the page

Comment: thanks, I tried this before, I defined a boolean property and assign it to true when the http returns error, and then bind it to <mat-error *ngIf = "property"> but it's won't work if the user added a second tag.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an async validator.

Check out this video by Kara Erickson (angular core team member, responsible for @angular/forms) on angular form validation.

[Angular Form Validation - Kara Erickson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kM5QBOWrUVI)

Comment: thank you, but I think that's I'm already using an async validator, the main difference here that the http service will add the value if it's not repeated.